# UnitOfWork nested queries

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert my old query to adapt my unitofwork repository pattern.

It's not liking my nested query and produces `An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments`

Original query

```
Clients = (from  z in ctx.Interactions
           where !z.Attendees
               .Any(y => ctx.LoanParties
                   .Any(party => party.Person_Id == y.Person.Id && 
                         select z).Count();
```

Unit Of Work query

```
Clients  = UnitOfWork.InteractionRepository.Get(
                z => !z.Attendees.Any(
                        y =>
                            !(UnitOfWork.LoanPartyRepository.Get(
                                party =>
                                    party.Person_Id == y.Person.Id).Any())))
                .Select(z => z)
                .AsParallel()
                .Count();
```

Intellisense doesn't like the `.Any()` at the end of the nested unitofwork query. May  I ask what is the correct syntax to do a nested query with unit of work?

Comment: The expression tree definitely isn't going to like that nested call to `Get()`.  Why not have the repositories on the unit of work just expose the `IQueryable` properties of `Interactions` and `LoanParties` directly?  I see no reason to change the footprint of the DAL by introducing those `Get()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be just missing some references.

However if you want to do this right, you should encapsulate the whole logic inside your repository (in order to work on IQueryable instead of IEnumerable). This way the query will be processed by database and will be faster. It'll also by reusable.

1. In your `InteractionRepository` create additional method like `GetWithSpecificCondition`
2. Move there as much of the code form you snipped as you can
3. Don't use LoanPartyRepository inside - just work on the DbContext